# using oauth with delicious and/or flickr

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo

First time question asker, long time question... lurker?

Anyways I am not new to coding or to php but I am new to oauth, and while it turns out I don't actually need oauth for this project it's really bugging me that I was failing on get_request_token on both delicious and flickr.

Following along with the instructions @ [delicious](http://www.delicious.com/help/oauthapi) I consistently and without fail get the result of "oauth_problem=signature_invalid" which leads me here.

I have the API/Consumer Key and the Consumer/Shared Secret and swapped in those values as well as a fresh time stamp into the example get url, but like I said without fail I get the signature invalid error.

I found delicious support threads that said to drop in "%26" on the signature when your signature method is plaintext but that didn't help, and I can't find any examples of people failing at such an early step, which is why I throw myself at the mercy of stack overflow...

I realize I am probably doing something stupid/foolish but I am a newb to oauth...

Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to get what you're asking, Could you post your code whithout ypur API key of course.

Comment: Theres not really any code to provide, I'm just following the step by step guide yahoo offers [link](http://www.delicious.com/help/oauthapi) and building out the parameters myself.

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating your oauth_signature incorrectly.  A common pain point is not including oauth_verifier in your oauth request, as per the [Oauth 1.0a specification](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#signing_process).

Since you didn't provide any code, nor any libs that you're using, I'm unable to validate what you're doing.